# how to fix array map is repeating values in loop?

Tags: php, array-map

i have this function written but it gives wrong output from array_map loop.
I want to return those values.
How can i do this.
Thanks in advance.

**Array values are=>**

```
$arr1 -   ([d 2] => 3000 [d 3] => 2000 [d deposit] => 4000 )<br>
$arr2 -    ( [w 2] => 2500 [w 3] => 2000 [w withdrawal] => 2000 )
```

**Code=>**

```
array_map(function ($v1,$v2) use ($arr_ddesc, $arr_wdesc) {
       echo array_search($v1,$arr_ddesc)."-".$v1." ,";
       echo array_search($v2,$arr_wdesc)."-".$v2." ,";
    },$arr_ddesc,$arr_wdesc);
```

**actual output=>**

```
d 2-3000 ,w  2-2500
d 3-2000 ,w 3-2000
d deposit-4000 ,w 3-2000
```

**desired output =>**

```
d 2-3000 ,w 2-2500
d 3-2000 ,w 3-2000
d deposit-4000 ,w withdrawal-2000
```

looks like last output for 2nd array is repeating

Comment: @NigelRen i edited the code now

Comment: `array_search` finds 2000 under `w 3` key and stops searching.

Comment: @u_mulder  how to fix this then?

Comment: Not use array search? What is the task here? Output key value pairs? If so - what's the purpose of `array_search`, simple `foreach`  will do the job.

Comment: @u_mulder  yes. i want to print 2 arrays simultaneously(1 pair of 1st array and 1 pair of 2nd array) in key and value pairs then again same on next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've invented this way of achieveing your goal:

```
array_map(
    function ($a, $b, $c, $d) { 
        // format as you need
        echo $a . '-' . $b . '; '. $c . '-' . $d . '<br />'; 
    }, 
    array_keys($arr1),
    $arr1,
    array_keys($arr2),
    $arr2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to loop over the values, this loops over the keys.  Then using the matching key (the one in the same position in the key array) from the second array it accesses the matching value...

```
$wdescKeys = array_keys($arr_wdesc);
foreach ( array_keys($arr_ddesc) as $position => $ddeskKey ) {
    echo $ddeskKey."-".$arr_ddesc[$ddeskKey]." ,";
    echo $wdescKeys[$position]."-".$arr_wdesc[$wdescKeys[$position]]." ,";
}
```